# R: Startup script on cluster

Tags: r, bash, cluster-computing

I would like R to run a script anytime I start up R. I am using R on a Linux cluster and I do not have access to R installation and the .Rprofile file and I cannot find it either. I can run R and have my local packages/libraries. For example, I would like to set the lib paths each time R is started.

```
.libPaths("path")
```

Is it possible to define and set a path for a custom startup script file?

In a non-interactive session, I could do in Bash something like

```
Rscript script.R
```

and my script.R has

```
.libPaths('path')
...
more code
...
```

Comment: Did you try to place a .Rprofile file in your home directory?

Comment: yes. but I don't think it does anything.

Comment: @rmf I know its long ago, did you find a solution to this ? I am also running on linux cluster

Comment: I created a .Rprofile in the home directory and added `.libPaths("/path/to/packages/")` and it seems to work.